# List subfolders of a specific asset folder

Tags: assets, assetfilemodel, subfolder

Is it possible to list subfolders from a specific folder?

Context: 
I'm printing out hundreds of icons which are maintained by moving a directory structure directly over to my public assets folder. Currently, I grab and list all icons by looking at the parent folder for icons:

```
{% for image in craft.assets.source('iconLibrary').limit(null) %}
   <li>...</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to call and list them by their individual folder names though. Is there a way to take a specific folder and return a list of subfolders?

**Update:**
Brad's solution works! Though it's somewhat awkward having to call an image first to start at AssetFileModel. Hopefully this can be optimized as I'm running through a loop like
 the one above for each child folder now—

```
<!--find image in parent icon folder to access folder via AssetFileModel.-->
{% for image in craft.assets.id('9328') %} 
   <!-- get children of that asset's folder -->
   {% for subfolder in image.folder.getChildren() %} //
      {{ subfolder }}   //prints each child folder name
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but in your example `image` if going to be an instance of [AssetFileModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel).

`AssetFileModel` has a [getFolder](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel#getFolder-detail) method that returns an instance of [AssetFolderModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFolderModel).

`AssetFolderModel` has a [getChildren](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/AssetFolderModel#getChildren-detail) method you could loop through to get all of the subfolders for the given folder.

Depending on how numerous your file/folder structure is, though, it might be more efficient to do this from PHP in a custom plugin rather than to do it from Twig.

Comment: Thanks, this gets it done. Is there a way to call a folder and get the children directly without starting from an image? I'm currently putting a tiny image that never gets displayed in the target folder for now in order to make that call.

Comment: `craft.assets.folderId(1).find()` will give an array of AssetFileModels for every image in that folder.